# Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created an app to be able to search care homes on a map and add new ones through a form.

Background: Everything worked in dev mode but in production the map was not refreshing to include the newly added care homes.The api to fetch the care home data was running at build time and after that subsequent requests return the same data ie don't include new data. (I don't understand why that was happening)

As a solution I used a server action to get the carehome data and return it to the client map component.

Now I am getting an warning saying that Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Objects with toJSON methods are not supported. Convert it manually to a simple value before passing it to props.

If you have any ideas why an api would only run at build time or how I can solve this warning I would really appreciate it. I am relatively beginner with next.js and development in general so apologies if this is not clear.

link to repo: https://github.com/niallam22/lottie/blob/main/src/app/components/careHomeMap.jsx

_actions.js

```
export async function getCareHomes(){
  try {
    await connectMongoDB();
    const careHomes = await CareHome.find();
    console.log('api/carehome careHomes: ',careHomes);
    // Return the list of care homes in the response
    return careHomes;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the query
    console.error('Error:', error);
    
    // Return an error response
    return { message: 'Error fetching care homes' };
  }
}
```

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getCareHomes } from '../_actions'


export default function CareHomeMap({ map, home }) {
  const [careHomeData, setCareHomeData] = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    try {
        getCareHomes().then(data =>{
          setCareHomeData(data)
        })

        // fetchCareHomes().then(data =>{
        //   setCareHomeData(data)
        // })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },[])
```

Comment: The issue is that NextJS caches the data.  This is a great thing to improve the performance of your app, but it can be frustrating if you don't understand how it works.  I suggest watching a tutorial such as this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJQbDPGzm0Y) which does a great job of introducing both the features of Next.JS and how to use them effectively.  Additionally, read the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching) on Caching.

Answer (score 15):

you should before passing data to page for use data, convert to string and so to json

data={JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(unit))}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: This worked. Serialisation

Comment: Thank you, this worked also for `nextJS 14.0.2`

Comment: Thank you, worked for me too. next 14.1.3

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are passing a server component to a client component and client component can only accept plain objects.
In your case, `careHomes` that you are getting from mongoDB is not a plain object. Documents coming from MongoDB has this `._id` which is a reference to a complex object. If you print out your return from mongoDB you'll see something like this(`_id`):

```
_id: new ObjectId('65aed9609c564bf65becf14a'),
  title: 'User Interface Enhancement',
  description: ' Improve the user interface of the application to enhance user experience and modernize the overall look and feel.',
  category: 'Projects',
  priority: 4,
  progress: 28,
```

I can recommend you 2 solutions:

1. use `.toString()`

```
careHomes._id = careHomes._id.toString()
```

2. Use a template string to pass the `._id`

```
`${careHomes._id}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused by `_id` from MongoDB not being a plain object, I have used `toString()` and it works.